# Generate the initial game board of a Candy-Crush-like game

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, nested-lists

I need to implement a function,
which returns a 6 by 6 matrix that fulfills the following requirements:

- The 36 numbers on the board must be 9 ones, 9 twos, 9 threes and 9 fours
- Any row or column must not contain 3 or more direct neighbours that are the same number
- The function return value must not be a constant
- Obviously it’s not allowed to use pre-calculated answers

correct answer:

```
    [[3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2],
    [2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4],
    [4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2],
    [4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4],
    [3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1],
    [3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4]]

   [[3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4],
    [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4],
    [4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3],
    [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1],
    [4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]]
```

wrong answer:

```
    [[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4],
    [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4],
    [4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3],
    [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1],
    [4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]]

   [[3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4],
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4],
    [4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3],
    [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1],
    [4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]]
```

Don’t need to worry too much about the academic time/space complexity. Focus more on the engineering point of view. Is there any good idea?

Comment: A backtracking could do the trick obviously. Another is to generate one randomly then ``crush'' every three-in-row and refill the remaining, until it stops?

Comment: Generate a random board with the correct distribution of 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s, and discard it if it doesn't meet the row/column conditions. As long as the valid boards are relatively common, this should work fine. It's called "acceptance sampling"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Note that this solution just generates a random board, checks if the conditions hold, and if not, generates another, so is not the most elegant solution.

**Code:**

```
from random import shuffle

def check_board(board):
    for row in board:
        if check_list(row):
            return False
    for i in range(len(board[0])):
        col = [row[i] for row in board]
        if check_list(col):
            return False
    return True

def check_list(lst):
    return any(lst[i]==lst[i+1] and lst[i]==lst[i+2] for i in range(len(lst)-2))

board = [[]]

while check_board(board):
    board = [1,2,3,4]*9
    shuffle(board)
    board = [board[i:i + 6] for i in range(0, len(board), 6)]

print(board)
```

**Example boards generated:**

```
[[3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3],
 [1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2],
 [4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4],
 [2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1]]

[[2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1],
 [3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4],
 [3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1],
 [2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2],
 [2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: It should work, but some quick napkin math indicates that the probability of generating a board without conflict might be less 1%

Comment: Agreed - were this to be scaled up this might become a problem, but `timeit` gives me an approximation of 48.6 µs ± 3.62 µs per valid generated board, so for this case it seems acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array of size 36 and fill it with your desired values => [1,1,1....4,4,4]
2. Apply Fisher-Yates shuffle to create a permutation of that array in O(n)
3. Check for the "3 in a row" rule and swap a random value if nesseccary, check again until the grid is free of that.